# Need to get String in one complex object using java 8(Optional<String>)

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have one object which contains multiple list. So, I traversed using map.
one object three list. Traversed using map and finally using find first.
Is it possible to take single Optional instead of

```
Optional<Optional<Optional<String>>>
```

??

This is what I have tried

```
Optional<Optional<Optional<String>>> myString = myComplexObject.stream()
                                .map( obj1 -> obj1.getObj2().stream()
                                          .map( obj2 -> obj2.getObj3().stream() 
                                                    .filter(obj3 -> obj3.getMyString() .equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) 
                                                    .map(obj3 -> obj3.getMyString())
                                                    .findFirst()) 
                                          .findFirst())
                                .findFirst();
```

Kindly help

Comment: This is wat I m tryingOptional<Optional<Optional<String>>> myString = myComplexObject
       .stream().map(
         obj1 -> obj1.getObj2()
           .stream().map(
             obj2 -> obj2.getObj3().stream()
               .filter(obj3 -> obj3.getMyString()
                 .equalsIgnoreCase("Name"))
               .map(obj3 -> obj3.getMyString()).findFirst())
           .findFirst())
       .findFirst();

Comment: @Sabarish include that in the question and make it readable.

Comment: @Sabarish You can always as the person asking the question, edit it and improve for the others to read.

Comment: Have you tried `flatMap` instead of `map`? This way, you can map a stream without having the nested optionals. Nesting Optionals does not seem to make sense, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `map()`, use `flatMap()`:

```
myComplexObject.stream()
.flatMap(obj1 -> obj1.getObj2().stream()) // Stream of `obj2`
.flatMap(obj2 -> obj2.getObj3().stream()) // Stream of `obj3`
.map(obj3 -> obj3.getMyString())          // Stream of `string`
.filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase("Name"))
.findFirst();
```

Comment: I tried to create the appropriate classes to get OP's code to compile and your solution does not compile where I can compile OP's code.

Comment: @Bentaye actually for obj3.getMyString use map() instead